# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I know there are many similarly to this question but I can't find a way.
I have a table and when I click edit in row table the modal should show and I want to pass data from  table to modal and display some data in modal that comes from my table .When the button click it always error and the modal didn't show.I been using Django.Please see the image below. Below is my current code. Can you help me please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwm3i.jpg)

> accounts.html

```
 {% extends 'navigation.html' %}
{% block content %}
<script> 
    function exampleModal(firstName,lastName){
       
            document.getElementById('firstNameValueId').innerHTML = firstName
            document.getElementById('secondNameValueId').innerHTML = lastName
            $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
        }
</script>

    <!-- mytable -->
    <div class="tabs-animation">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header-tab card-header">
                <div class="card-header-title font-size-lg text-capitalize font-weight-normal"><i
                        class="header-icon lnr-laptop-phone mr-3 text-muted opacity-6"> </i>Accounts Information
                </div>
                <div class="btn-actions-pane-right actions-icon-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                            class="btn-icon btn-icon-only btn btn-link">
                            <i class="pe-7s-menu btn-icon-wrapper"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown-menu-right rm-pointers dropdown-menu-shadow dropdown-menu-hover-link dropdown-menu">
                            <h6 tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-header">Header</h6>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-inbox"> </i><span>Menus</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-file-empty"> </i><span>Settings</span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="dropdown-icon lnr-book"> </i><span>Actions</span>
                            </button>
                            <div tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <div class="p-3 text-right">
                                <button class="mr-2 btn-shadow btn-sm btn btn-link">View Details</button>
                                <button class="mr-2 btn-shadow btn-sm btn btn-primary">Action</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                 <table style="width: 100%;" id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                         
                            <th>Date joined</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    {% for user_information in user_information %}
                        <tr>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info" onclick="exampleModal('{{user_information.first_name}}','{{user_information.last_name}}')">Edit</a></td>
                            <td>{{user_information.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{user_information.username}}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>  
                </table>
                
                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

    <!-- This is my modal -->
<div id="modal-div">
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Personal Information</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
            
                    <form action="#" method="post">
                        <label for="firstname">  <p id="firstNameValueId">Some text in the Modal..</p></label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="custom-input1 form-control " id="firstNameValueId" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondNameValueId" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The very first mistake is that `firstNameValueId ` is given as id to two different elements.
secondly, I think you are trying to show some value in input then try using .value instead of innerHtml

Comment: @jaswanth thanks for your response, you mean that I should delete the other one elements in my modal?

Comment: `id` NEEDS to be unique, there can NOT be two or more elements  with same `id's`. Its is called `get Element By Id` NOT  `get ElementS By Id`

Comment: @ikiK thanks for your response, I already applied what you're suggesting but the result is always the same, please help me https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwm3i.jpg

Comment: Are u using `.value` like first comment suggested not `.innerHtml`?

Comment: @ikiK Yes this is what it looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwm3i.jpg

Comment: @ikiK I tried just showing the modal to my script but it didn't show the modal, please check out the part of my modal if I correctly called the Id thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry cant help you, never used modal...

Comment: @D-jason I have used a fiddle to check your html and it seems to be working fine if this what you can see in browser elements https://jsfiddle.net/jaswanth098/wc6hosu1/4/

Comment: @jaswanth Thank you! I the code seems right and there is no problem . The only problem that I used {% extends 'sample.html '% } .In my main sample.html which has been extended  the javascript seems does not support bootstrap.js. My current problem is on this link now   [links][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895994/modal-not-showing-in-html-file].When I put  those script src bootstrap it conflicts the User Interface of my template, and now I'm about to surrender and resign  :) But anyway I appreciate your very effort  you're my man!

Comment: @jaswanth it works! now thank you, the problem is on my template,the version of my bootstrap . Previously I used bootstrap 3.4.1 and I change it to bootstrap 4.5.2 and it shows the modal.