# Modal not showing in HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is not a rare problem, but I can't find a solution yet. I just want to show the modal when I click the button using JavaScript. But it always shows an error when I click the button and the modal doesn't show up. below is my current problem and question

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

> Now then when I add these scripts it affect the UI and css in my web system. My question is there any specific code from these following script that can be only used in modal? and I just copy and paste to my main js and css without affecting the UI THANKS!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML file:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td><button onclick="myFunction()">
              Basic Modal</button>
              </td>
            </tr>                   
         </tbody>
</table>

<!-- this is my modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="mb-0">This is sample modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<!-- my javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {

     $("#exampleModal").modal()
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! The problem is my template.If used bootstrap 3.4.1 the modal didn't show but when I replace and change it to bootstrap 4.5.2 it works now and it shows the modal. the problem is the version of the bootstrap I used.

Answer (score 0):

You need add these css and javascript library at head tag

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {

     $("#exampleModal").modal()
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<table style="width: 100%;" id="example" class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Airi Satou</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>33</td>
              <td>2008/11/28</td>
              <td><button onclick="myFunction()">
              Basic Modal</button>
              </td>
            </tr>                   
         </tbody>
</table>

<!-- this is my modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="mb-0">This is sample modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works!, but it change the UI of the html if I add those script src. How could I maintain the UI ? some plugins has been change @Hien Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the jQuery/JavaScript file not added to the HTML file properly. This goes out and gets the jQuery code from the source. You could download that and reference it locally on the server which would be faster.

Or either one can directly link it to jQuery or GoogleCDN or MicrosoftCDN.

and also add this files-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and write -

```
$('#modalId').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thank you it works!, but it change the UI of the html if I add those script src. How could I maintain the UI ? some plugins has been change @SJR

Comment: can you please share the picture of your UI?

Comment: I used template this is what looks like Before https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXu6M.png   and                                After https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJBo3.png @SJR It change the fonts and some css design

Comment: I got your point. It's changing your css because you are using template. If you want to use template then you have to add template css files instead of bootstrap css files. So, remove bootstrap css  files and add template css and js files

Comment: that's the point if I remove the bootstrap that you're suggest earlier, the result was Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined :(

Answer (score 0):

Include bootstrap and Jquery library in your head tag to make it work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response it works, but it change the UI of the html if I add those script src. How could I maintain the UI ? some plugins has been change. I used template design @Saniyasyedqureshi